# JMeter - need to loop through the array

Tags: arrays, json, loops, jmeter

I am using JSON Path Extractor and I am getting back an array:

```
DeedIDs=["5411ab7ccbda71fb38f5adf9","5411ab7dcbda71fb38f5adfa","55d7000dfbffa917247e09bf","5411ab7acbda71fb38f5adf4","5411ab79cbda71fb38f5adf3","5408b9e2cbda7138f4452129","5408b9e2cbda7138f445212a"]
DeedIDs_1=5411ab7ccbda71fb38f5adf9
DeedIDs_2=5411ab7dcbda71fb38f5adfa
DeedIDs_3=55d7000dfbffa917247e09bf
DeedIDs_4=5411ab7acbda71fb38f5adf4
DeedIDs_5=5411ab79cbda71fb38f5adf3
DeedIDs_6=5408b9e2cbda7138f4452129
DeedIDs_7=5408b9e2cbda7138f445212a
DeedIDs_matchNr=7
```

I need to make a call for each of DeedIDs. I am getting `DeedIDs_x` but when I try to enter it inside `${DeedIDs_${counter_value}}` it doesn't work. I tried several formats, but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function

> The V (variable) function returns the result of evaluating a variable name expression.

In you case use:

```
 ${__V(DeedIDs_${counter_value})}
```

Answer (score 6):

For what you want to do, it's better to use a [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) instead of a Loop Controller:

[image]

It will automatically iterate on **DeedIDs_x** and put each value in **${DeedID}**

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve and what is the most convenient for you:

- [`${__evalVar(DeedIDs_${counter_value})}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar)
- [`${__V(DeedIDs_${counter_value})}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)
- [`${__groovy(vars.get('DeedIDs_' + vars.get('counter_value')),)}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)